# Is it possible to set up 1..* websites in Azure with one base price?

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows, azure, amazon-route53

In reviewing [The World's Greatest Azure Demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7V8HikBP1vQ) (9:00), I see that the basic cost for one website is $9.77/month (plus hourly up-time cost).

In AWS, for example, I have a Windows server configured with roughly 30 running websites through IIS.  No additional cost per website, other than the Route 53 Hosted Zones (domain name pointing - $0.11/domain).

I may be understanding the Azure pricing incorrectly... it would appear that it would cost roughly $293 just to host those 30 domains in Azure, is that correct?

Is there a standard IIS type interface to Azure where I can add 1..* domains on a given server?

Comment: What do you mean by "1..*"?

Comment: I would guess its "from one to many"

Answer (score 1):

> it would appear that it would cost roughly $293 just to host those 30 domains in Azure, is 
>   that correct?

If you set it up like this, yes. You can always rent a virtual machine in azure, too, and set up as many sites there as you want.

Comment: In trying to equate it to the AWS world, would it would be similar to AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployments?

Through Visual Studio you can deploy directly to Azure.  Will it only deploy in that scenario (similar to Beanstalk), or can you deploy to a site residing on a VM?  Is website autoscaling only available in this scenario, and can we do a server auto-scaling instead?

Comment: I have no idea because I never used AWS nor do I care about it. (I also do not use Azure, outside of development - but I do follow their offerings).